# Problemas ao fazer insert simples no banco - Unexpected Token

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estou tendo problemas ao fazer inserções no banco de dados, alguém poderia me indicar quais os possíveis problemas?

SQL 1:

```
INSERT INTO data_inicio (data_sys, descricao)
VALUES (NOW(),'Data de inicio');
```

Erro nessa sql: Unexpected token near 'Data de inicio'

SQL 2:

```
INSERT INTO curso_desconto (id_curso,id_desconto) VALUES((SELECT 
MAX(id) FROM curso), '1');
```

Erro nessa sql: a comma or a closing bracket was expected

Comment: Ficou resolvido?

Comment: Sim, respondi minha pergunta para mostrar a resolução.

Answer (score 1):

Usando a sintaxe `INSERT INTO <<table_name>> VALUES ((...))` você deve fornecer valores literais, ao invés de funções como `NOW()`.

Isto está definido na [documentação oficial do MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> The `INSERT ... VALUES` and `INSERT ... SET` [are] forms of the statement insert rows based on explicitly specified values.

Já para inserir o resultado de select, também conhecido como `'INSERT SELECT'`, [a sintaxe seria assim](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO <<table_name>> [(column_name1, column_name2, ...)] SELECT 5, NOW()
```

*Sem escrever o `'VALUES'`*

[Veja um exemplo do seu caso funcionando no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cc284/1)

Answer (score 0):

Com as sugestões feitas a mim, não consegui resolver o problema, porém consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Ao invés de usar o now() usei CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ficando a 1 query assim:

```
INSERT INTO data_inicio (data_sys, descricao)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'Data de inicio');
```

Já no segundo caso, consegui resolver pegando o id máximo jogando pra uma variável, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT @max := MAX(curso.id)  FROM curso;
INSERT INTO curso_desconto (id_curso,id_desconto) VALUES(@max, '1');
```

Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar!